# Android launcher resizes constantly

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am developing an enterprise app that runs in a custom kiosk mode (I run it as a launcher), but I notice my app getting constant resize messages, like these:

```
MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 2048, 1536) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=2
Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][2048,1536] newFrame=[0,0][2048,1536] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true -889108480} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
```

And by constant, I mean every 30-40 seconds.

I have tried to work around the issue, by telling android I will handle screensizes (In the manifest I added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`), but that doesn't seem to work.

I noticed that right before the app resizes, the status bar moves up and away, but even when I hide the statusbar in my app, it still does it at that interval.

The issue arises when I go into my kiosk mode (set the app as a launcher), but only after I tell my app to reset itself (I clear the database and start my main activity again). I have no idea why this can cause my app to start trying to rotate.

Comment: I think the resize messages might be a symptom of another config change, not it's cause. I would @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) and look for specific Configuration changes which happen at the times you specify. Anyway, this scenario might be device/OS dependent. Does this actually present a problem or is it just a random artifact that you noticed?

Comment: @Bjelis it is a significant issue and I can reproduce it every time with a common scenario for my app. I will check the configuration changes and try to determine the issue.